# Can I use Autodesk Sketchbook for free?

Tags: software-rec, drawing

There are 2 options on the main page: 'download free' and 'go pro'. Further there is such phrase: 'Download SketchBook and log in to activate your Free 15 Day Trial of Pro membership.' It's confusing. Can I use it as long as I want for free ?

Comment: They have a free version, and you can "trial" the pro version for 15 days.

Comment: There's a basic version with limited functionality.

Comment: @fixer1234 It's confusing too, where can I ask them ?

Comment: @Darius sure ? why it's not an answer ?

Comment: No, you have to pay hundreds of dollars for it like any other Autodesk product, unless you want to sail the high seas. Either way, this is not something we can help you with.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not part of Autodesk so I can't say 100% for sure and I haven't downloaded it as I don't have a need for it.

From the wording on their Download Page [here](https://www.sketchbook.com/thankyou) they wrote 
`Try SketchBook's Pro membership
Download SketchBook and log in to activate your 
Free 15 Day Trial of Pro membership.`

My understanding is we are getting free stuff, and if you want to try the pro version, you need to sign up to try for 15 days. If they meant something else, then yes

And then I also found this page that shows the difference between free and pro which hopefully helps you to decide whether free is good enough, or you need Pro version.

https://support.sketchbook.com/hc/en-us/articles/209671948-SketchBook-desktop-v7-What-are-the-main-feature-differences-between-the-free-and-paid-membership-accounts-

I hope this helps